# How to perform thresholding on a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

Following is my code:

```
...
result=tf.div(product_norm,denom)
    if(result>0.5):
        result=1
    else:
        result=0
    return result
```

If the value in a tensor is less than 0.5 then it should be replaced with 0 otherwise 1. But it keeps returning the error.

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this simple case, you can use

```
result = tf.cast(result + 0.5, tf.int32)
```

When if-statement becomes more complex, consider using [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#cond)

Comment: I tried outputing it and it returns this :Tensor("Cast:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)

Comment: You cannot get a value that tensor holds unless you run it within session. Consider referring to [Tensorflow Mechanics 101](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/tf/)

Comment: I'm not talking about value here. Why is the shape parameter void? And I did run it within a session

Comment: Should the tensor not have some shape?

Comment: It is called unit shape. Unit shape parameter means it is rank 0 tensor, i.e. a scalar. tf.cast preserves shape, as well as elementwise addition (+) does. If you print your result before this operation you will see it also has unit shape

Comment: Thanks it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is

```py
result = tf.where(result>0.5, 1,0)
```

The documentation of `tf.where(condition, x, y)` explains what happens:

> If x and y are also provided (both have non-None values) the condition tensor acts as a mask that chooses whether the corresponding element / row in the output should be taken from x (if the element in condition is True) or y (if it is False).